# Batch Commands - to open multiple URL in one Internet Explorer in one tab

Tags: internet-explorer, url, batch-file

I am writing a .bat file to open multiple url in one internet explorer in one tab.

I am able to open multiple url in multiple IE windows.

```
echo start...opening the url..
start "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer" IEXPLORE.EXE www.google.com
start "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer" IEXPLORE.EXE www.yahoo.com
start "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer" IEXPLORE.EXE www.facebook.com
```

But I actually wants to open one IE window ( one tab ) and i want to open the next url in the same tab ( neither in other tab nor in other IE window ).

Please let me know what is best way to achieve this.
Any idea would be very useful to me.

Comment: What is the point of this? Unless you're putting in some kind of pause it's just going to overwrite each page until you're just left with facebook. Is it just to launch the page so the session gets logged in automatically?

Comment: Yes you are all most right... in real time, I need to go to First page then login into this page and redirect to 2nd page and from 2nd page i need to run 3rd page.. so i want everything to be in one tab only... hope u got my point... @MattWilliamson

Comment: I can't seem to find any documentation indicating that Internet Explorer has this capability from the command line. However, I would recommend that you use a different browser in the first place. Chrome will open new web pages in the same window under different tabs by default.

Comment: Internet Explorer, as far as I know (I haven't personally tested this), works similarly to Chrome in that. @unclemeat

Comment: @impinball, It didn't work for me, using IE9. Perhaps IE10 has this feature.

Comment: I have to internet explorer, this mandatory for me. I am able to open three urls in three tabs in one IE window.. now the point is to open in One Tab. @unclemeat

Comment: @unclemeat I forgot to clarify...it should open in different windows (MS was apparently never smart enough to check for an already-running process of IE...maybe IE11 has this feature, but I know IE10 opens a new window by default, like most other built-in Windows programs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only do this with vbs. Save the following as IENav.vbs and double click it. Make sure IE is open prior to doing so.

```
    Dim ShellApp, ShellWindows, IE
    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set ShellWindows = ShellApp.Windows()
    Dim i
    For i = 0 To ShellWindows.Count - 1
        If InStr(ShellWindows.Item(i).FullName, "iexplore.exe") <> 0 Then
          Set IE = ShellWindows.Item(i) 
        End If
    Next
    IE.Navigate2("http://www.google.com")
    wscript.sleep 3000
    IE.Navigate2("http://www.yahoo.com")
    wscript.sleep 3000
    IE.Navigate2("http://www.facebook.com")

    set ShellWindows = Nothing
    set ShellApp = Nothing
    set IE = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Same window, same tab --I don't think you can do that in IE unless you write your own frameset page, and open google in one frame and yahoo in another frame... the only way is to create a html page that pulls content from two websites and displays them side-by-side. A frameset is one way of doing this:

```
<HTML>
  <FRAMESET cols="50%,50%">
    <FRAME src="http://www.google.com/">
    <FRAME src="http://www.yahoo.com/">
  </FRAMESET>
</HTML>
```

However, many websites do not allow their content to be displayed in frames due to security reasons. Both Google and Twitter block frames... There may be other ways to accomplish this that are not blocked by websites, like using <**iframe**> elements. Still, the solution is a static page like the frameset example above.

You could easily write a batch file that would let you pass in two domain names on the command line, the batch file could generate the static html file and then open it, which would display the content of two or more websites on a single page (as in the example above).

Comment: Thanks for ur ans but i dnt want to create any html page... with bat file i have to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

I had this happen to me in work when opening multiple urls in a batch file and it was behaviour I did not want.

Have a look at Tools/Internet Options/Advanced/Re use windows....

You have to switch tabbed browsing off (it states), but I believe our version of IE in work might not support tabbed browsing, being so old. By disabling this option I got each url in a new window, which is what I was trying to achieve.